# jBoss deployment of message-driven bean spec violation

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss-mdb, message-driven-bean

I have an java EE application which has one message-driven bean and it runs fine on JBoss 4, however when I configure the project for JBoss 6 and deploy on it, I get this error;

```
WARN  [org.jboss.ejb.deployers.EjbDeployer.verifier] EJB spec violation:

...

The message driven bean must declare one onMessage() method.

...

org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Verification of Enterprise Beans failed, see above for error messages.
```

But my bean HAS the onMessage method! It would not have worked on jboss 4 either then.

Why do I get this error!?

**Edit:**

The class in question looks like this

```
package ...
imports ...

public class MyMDB implements MessageDrivenBean, MessageListener {
AnotherSessionBean a;
OneMoreSessionBean b;

public MyMDB() {}

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        try {
                //Lookup sessionBeans by jndi, create them
                lookupABean();
                // check message-type, then invokie
                a.handle(message);
                // else
                b.handle(message);

            } catch (SomeException e) { 
                  //handling it 
            } 
     }
}

public void lookupABean() {
    try {
         // code to lookup session beans and create.
    } catch (CreateException e) { // handling it and catching NamingException too }
}
}
```

**Edit 2:**
And this is the jboss.xml relevant parts

```
<message-driven>
<ejb-name>MyMDB</ejb-name>
<destination-jndi-name>topic/A_Topic</destination-jndi-name>
<local-jndi-name>A_Topic</local-jndi-name>
<mdb-user>user</mdb-user>
<mdb-passwd>pass</mdb-passwd>
<mdb-client-id>MyMessageBean</mdb-client-id>
<mdb-subscription-id>subid</mdb-subscription-id>
<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>jms/TopicFactory</res-ref-name>
<jndi-name>jms/TopicFactory</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
</message-driven>
```

**Edit 3:**

I just removed all my jars from the project, and only re-added relevant ones (from new versions also) to put out NoClassDefFound errors. 
Still the problem remains.

**Edit:**
Any directions, what area should I look at? My project, or jboss-configration, or the deployment settings??

Comment: Can we see the class that implements `onMessage()`?

Comment: It is calling another session bean after checking the message, why? Cant I do whatever I can normally do in a method?

Comment: @skaffman, updated the question with the mb bean code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> org.jboss.ejb.deployers.EjbDeployer.verifier

looks for

```
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message)
```

via some code like this (this is from JBoss5):

```
    /**
     * Check if the given message is the onMessage() method
     */
    public boolean isOnMessageMethod(Method m)
     {
       if ("onMessage".equals(m.getName()))
       {
          Class[] paramTypes = m.getParameterTypes();
          if (paramTypes.length == 1)
          {
             if (Message.class.equals(paramTypes[0]))
                return true;
          }
       }
       return false;
    }
```

It is important that the parameter type is `javax.jms.Message` and nothing else, for example some subclass or superclass or some implementing class.

Your signature is `public void onMessage(Message message)` which looks ok on first sight.

A `Class` is equal only in its `ClassLoader`. If for some reasons `javax.jms.Message` is available in different classloaders in the same JVM, strange things can happen, depending on the ClassLoader of the EjbDeployer.verifier. Maybe the EjbDeployer.verifer has a access to `javax.jms.Message` in another ClassLoader as `MyMDB`. As result, both `javax.jms.Message` are not equal to each other, although they are the same byte-code and literally exists. The EjbVerifier will warn about missing `onMessage`, because `javax.jms.Message` on ClassLoader A is not equal to `javax.jms.Message` on ClassLoader B.

This can happen when libraries with `javax.jms.Message` is copied on wrong places on the JBoss AS. So I guess - from a distance - that there is some jars containing `javax.jms.Message` in wrong places on the JBoss or the EAR. For example some wrong jbossallclient.jar in the EAR.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your EAR does not contain its own copies of the `javax.ejb` classes (or any `javax` classes at all, for that matter). JBoss 4 and 6 have rather different classloading semantics, and what works on one may not work on the other.  For example, if your EAR's `lib` contained its own copies of `Message` or `MessageListener`, then it may no longer work.

Comment: I just checked and there is no javax related jars in my ear, or in any of the jars or wars in the ear.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out on "JBossAS [6.0.0.20100911-M5 "Neo"]" and Eclipse Helios

```
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenBean;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"
    ) }, 
    mappedName = "topic/A_Topic", 
    messageListenerInterface = MessageListener.class)
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener, MessageDrivenBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4923389997501209506L;

    public MyMDB() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public void ejbRemove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

And this setting works. Do you have the same imports for your bean (perhaps there was an automatic import gone wrong???)