# EJB Spec violation: The message driven bean must declare one onMessage() method

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am working on some migration project, involves moving around quite a few stuff from Ant/CVS/Jboss4/Java5 to Maven/SVN/Jboss7/Java6 - this gets nasty.

First step, I am working on moving the ant build to maven - that it in iteslf involve a lot of complication. Now that I get the ear file built, and I compared it with the ear from ant build, I think I got it good with the maven build.

Now, deploying on Jboss4 first, I encouter

```
[ejb.EJBDeployer.verifier] EJB spec violation:
Warning: The message driven bean must declare one onMessage() method.

2011-11-08 15:25:03,079 ERROR (Thread: main) [jboss.deployment.MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/opt/jboss-4.0.3SP1/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp46514Billing-EAR-1.0.ear-contents/processsubscriptionbean-1.0.jar
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Verification of Enterprise Beans failed, see above for error messages.
        at org.jboss.ejb.EJBDeployer.create(EJBDeployer.java:575)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:141)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.invoke(AbstractInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.invoke(ModelMBeanOperationInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.DynamicInterceptor.invoke(DynamicInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:74)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:245)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:644)
        at org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanProxyExt.invoke(MBeanProxyExt.java:176)
        at $Proxy24.create(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:935)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.create(MainDeployer.java:925)
        at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:789)
```

I came across this thread [jBoss deployment of message-driven bean spec violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461821/jboss-deployment-of-message-driven-bean-spec-violation) - so I figured I was using the wrong library on my new maven build, I replaced it and made sure it's using the same javax.jms library (this now points to the same jar containing javax.jms.Message as the original ant build) - in fact I simply grabbed the jar referenced by the ant build and upload it to maven repo and reference it from my maven build.

But I still encounter the above problem. The original ant-build would deploy with no problem, but currently I am stuck at this issue for the maven-build ear.

Any suggestion on what other steps i can take to make sure there are no different class files issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the javax.jms library being packaged in your ear (jboss-j2ee.jar, jboss-client.jar, etc)? If so, you don't want that since you want to use the one provided by the app server. You can fix this by changing the dependency in your pom to have the `<scope>provided</scope>` for anything that shouldn't be in your ear.

Comment: thanks! ... I encounter more variations that solved by the same solution